# Why does mail always come from @localhost on my ubuntu server from exim4?

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim, localhost

I have an up-to-date Ubuntu Server (14.04.01) and want to be able to send out status e-mails.  I've also got 2 other computers running Debian Sid.

I have exim4 installed on all 3.  I've gone through "sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config" on all 3 of them, and all 3 have the same settings.

When I send mail from my Debian boxes, it comes from the correct address (root@sr66-darter.hda.surfrock66.com for example) but whenever I send mail from my server, it comes from root@localhost or user@localhost.

I've validated /etc/hosts, /etc/hostname, I've re-run through dpkg-reconfigure...nothing seems to change it.  I can post any config outputs as needed.  Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT: By request, full headers of a sample email:

```
Delivered-To: surfrock66@surfrock66.com
Received: by 10.112.164.198 with SMTP id ys6csp308507lbb;
        Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:51:19 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.70.27.225 with SMTP id w1mr43034811pdg.40.1415739078530;
        Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:51:18 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <surfrock66@localhost>
Received: from localhost (c-98-255-144-176.hsd1.ca.comcast.net. [98.255.144.176])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id oj8si20849377pbb.207.2014.11.11.12.51.17
        for <surfrock66@surfrock66.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:51:18 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: surfrock66@localhost does not designate permitted sender hosts)     client-ip=98.255.144.176;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: surfrock66@localhost does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=surfrock66@localhost
Received: from surfrock66 by localhost with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <surfrock66@localhost>)
    id 1XoIQI-0005bx-WC
    for surfrock66@surfrock66.com; Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:52:23 -0800
Subject: SR66 Network Mapping: Scanned 2014.11.11 12:40
To: <surfrock66@surfrock66.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)
Message-Id: <E1XoIQI-0005bx-WC@localhost>
From: surfrock66 <surfrock66@localhost>
    Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:52:22 -0800
```

Comment: Can you post the full headers of the email received from root@localhost?

Comment: How exactly is the mail generated? What does your exim config look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to set up an alias in /etc/email-addresses to identify the "from" address for each of your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `/etc/mailname`.  This is the normally the file that contains the domain name used to qualify addresses.

Comment: Nope, that file has the correct name in it.  Curious though, I'd never seen that file before.